# Multiple simultaneous accounts in Mutt

Tags: mutt

I've set up my Mutt config to handle several inboxes using folder hooks, and it's working great, but is there any way to monitor multiple accounts at the same time?

With my current setup, I won't be notified of new mail unless I switch to the account manually, which kind of defeats the purpose of notification.

My muttrc:

```
set sidebar_visible = yes
set sort = threads

bind index,pager \Cj sidebar-next
bind index,pager \Ck sidebar-prev
bind index,pager \Cl sidebar-open

bind index,pager <delete> purge-message
bind index l display-message

auto_view text/html
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html

source ~/.mutt/theme

source ~/.mutt/work/muttrc
source ~/.mutt/personal/muttrc

set realname = 'My name'
```

My work and personal emails are set up like this:

```
color status cyan default

set from                    = user@email.com

set smtp_url                = smtps://user@smtp.email.com/
set smtp_pass               = MY_PASS
unset smtp_authenticators

set ssl_force_tls           = yes
set ssl_starttls            = yes
unset ssl_use_sslv3
unset timeout

set imap_user               = user@email.com
set imap_pass               = MY_PASS

set folder                  = imaps://user@imap.email.com/
set spoolfile               = +INBOX
set record                  = +Sent
set postponed               = +Drafts

mailboxes +INBOX

folder-hook imaps://user@imap.email.com/* source ~/.mutt/work/muttrc
```

Comment: My (neo)mutt IMAP-fu is too weak, but I think you can't monitor multiple IMAP accounts for incoming mail at the same time using native (neo)mutt builtin imap. You can sync your IMAP accounts with offlineimap, isync or similar tool and define mailboxes as paths to the maildirs. Then it would work as expected.